# How to use Exceptionally stage in CompletableFuture objects in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, arcore

I want to use ARCore with Xamarin and I stuck with error handling in CompletableFuture objects for example ModelRenderable.Builder(). Documentation says that I should use Exceptionally() function but I can't find any samples how to do it in C#.

In Xamarin Exceptionally() function require to use something that implements Java.Util.Function.IFunctions interface but my very simple class throws "Specified cast is not valid" error on runtime. Does anyone know how to use Exceptionally() function?

```java
//here is java code how this should be implemented
ModelRenderable.builder()
  .setSource(this, Uri.parse("..."))
  .build()
  .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable2 = renderable)
  .exceptionally(
    throwable -> {
     //show error
     return null;
  });
```

```cs
//here is my code in C#
var builder = new ModelRenderable.Builder();
builder.SetSource(this, Uri.parse("..."));
builder.Build()
  .ThenAccept(new RenderableConsumer(renderable => AddNodeToScene(renderable)))
  .Exceptionally(new Foo(() => { throw new Exception("error"); }));
```

```cs
//here is my very simple implementation of IFunction interface
internal class Foo : Java.Lang.Throwable, IFunction
{
  public Foo(Action action) { }

  public Java.Lang.Object Apply(Java.Lang.Object t)
  {
    return t;
  }                        
}
```

EDITED

```cs
//alternative approach to ThenAccept() but in this case Exception is also not thrown
 builder.Build().GetAsync()
 .ContinueWith(renderable => AddNodeToScene((Renderable)renderable.Result), new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
 .ContinueWith(error => new Exception("Error!"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: when you use ModelRenderable, what dll did you reference?

Comment: ModelRenderable can be found in Xamarin.Android.SceneForm.Assets nuget package but requires version 1.10 or higher. It was missing in previous versions. It is a part of Xamarin.Android.SceneForm.Rendering.dll and Google.AR.Sceneform.Rendering namespace.

Comment: I search some info, but I don't find any ways to use C#, if you just add function in Exceptionally(), it don't works?

Comment: I added new snippet that uses ContinueWith() instead of ThenAccept(), that loading data but not re-throwing errors. 2nd ContinueWith() is not activated when there is an error on the first one. 
I can't use just Exceptionally() because it requires object that is Java.Util.Functions.IFunction and I can't crate such object or find any working sample.

Comment: D, Anything update?